# How do I set up a GPU with CUDA in python for TensorFlow on Windows 10?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to use TensorFlow but any time I try and run something I get an error saying that I need to set up a GPU on my machine. I've heard that I need to download some sort of CUDA attachments to run it, not too sure though...

```
2020-11-18 11:23:57.579846: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I have a Dell xps 15 9570 so I have a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 1050 Ti GPU. I think that this is enough hardware to run TensorFlow but am not too sure.

Comment: Have you installed the CUDA runtime libraries?

Comment: I don't think so. Can I pip install them?

Comment: You need to install tensorflow-gpu. Follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZFn0dvPZUQ and make changes according to your system specifications

Comment: On the video, it says to check if your graphics card is listed on the Nvidia cuda enabled products list. I checked and the NVIDIA RTX 1050 is on the list but not the RTX 1050 Ti. Does that mean that it can't run on my device. Link to website: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: The RTX 1050 Ti supports CUDA, that shouldn't be an issue. If you haven't installed the CUDA runtime, you can't add that through pip, it needs to be a system level install. Try following the guide at https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781 and substitute the relevant versions to reflect your tensorflow install and system.

Comment: You have mentioned NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti GPU in your post and you are mentioning NVIDIA RTX 1050 Ti in the comments!!

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, it was meant to be the RTX 1050 Ti GPU.

Comment: The XPS 15 9570 ships with a GTX 1050 Ti, which is a Pascal architecture and has a compute capability of 6.1, so will support CUDA up to I believe v11 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will encounter any problem with your current NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti

You need to get TensorFlow GPU. You can't directly `pip install` tensorflow GPU. You need the set up the configurations required to run Tensorflow GPU just like how you installed python for the first time on your machine. You need to install CUDA Tool kit and many other things. It can be a hefty process installing it for the first time so make sure you are following some guide which will save you a lot of trouble. Once the set-up is done I'd recommend installing tensorflow-gpu using anaconda. That way you can specify the version as well.

Follow this tutorial [Tensorflow GPU](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows-cuda-cudnn/). I did it and it works perfectly.

There's lot of other tutorials on YouTube you can follow through. Some of them has been already highlighted in the comment section.